# How do I create a customized dialog box for web app in vb.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, web-applications

I have a web application and depending on the cases/instances, it will trigger a warning. I know there's Alert/Confirm from javascript but apparently, the dialog box needs to have Yes or No Button and depends on the user language, it could be english or french for the buttons. How do I do this? Also the warning messages I put will be coming from the database. So it would be nice if I could call it on code behind. Thank you!

Comment: Have a search for "jquery dialog".

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but how do dynamically change the button of dialog box on code behind?

Comment: You could use `<asp:Literal>` elements to put the language-specific data into the page in the appropriate places.